# dovecot mixed Maildir and mdbox mailboxes

Tags: email-server, dovecot, mailbox

I try to move all mailboxes from Maildir do mdbox but I have to do in online and mailbox by mailbox.

I use setup with VimbAdmin and there are homedir and maildir variables

now my setup looks like this

10-mail.conf

```
mail_location: Maildir:/home/vmail/domain.tld/user
```

and in database fields are:

```
homedir    /home/vmail/domain.tld/user
maildir    maildir:/home/vmail/domain.tld/user:LAYOUT=fs
```

I've tried to change them to:

```
homedir    /home/vmail/domain.tld/user
maildir    mdbox:/home/vmail/domain.tld/user
```

but nothing happened.

when i changed mail_location in 10-mail.conf to **"auto:"** i got such error:

```
Error: user user@domain.tld: Initialization failed: Namespace '': Autodetection failed for auto: (home=/home/vmail/.home/domain.tld/user)
Error: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
```

and no one can login then, even the user with mdbox settings.

Any hints how to make this work?

Comment: `Refer to server log for more information.` And what's there?

Comment: @nysander:  Have you tried using `dsync` for offline migration?  I believe you can provide a list of mailboxes and they will be tried in order.

Comment: @sebbix - this is all from server log what I've pasted above

Comment: @billthor i've done     doveadm sync migration of this mailbox and it is converted do mdbox but when I log to this mailbox only emails from maildir are visible and new one are stored in maildir not in mdbox

Comment: @nysander You will need to change the delivery method of your mail server if you want it delivered to the mailbox.  You can continue to use Maildir for the inbox by specifying it in the location parameter.  You will need to specify the location as autodetection looks for Maildir before mdbox.